# SubView hides some of my labels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a text field in my view. when I am editing this text field table view should come just to create intellisense . This table view covers labels in my view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    txtcity.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;


    [viewForautoCompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

**still my labels are not visible**

Comment: check the value in labels because i think blank labels also seems to invisible.

Comment: @Rizzu some part of my label is visible and another part not visible

Comment: Ok then check for the width of your label and i suspect that some of your other control overlap your label.

Comment: the middile part of my label is not visible.it is below the tableview

Comment: shall i need to import any files for proper operation

Comment: No need to import any other thing, how your label is showing? like abc...abc?

Comment: my label is two lines like "abc      abc" it is showing like this

Comment: i have created a view and for that view i added the table view.actually my table view is below the textfield.when iam changing data in text field the tableview has to be appear and when i select the row my tableview is disappear and still my view hides my label.

Comment: the table height may change bcoz data is coming from service.

Comment: all this is to create a intellisense in xcode

Comment: in iphone it is working but in ipad it is not working

Comment: in my app iam facing this problem at three places. at all of these i created a view. thank u